# Divide into grid and Mosaic using google earth?

Tags: google-earth, scale, mosaic, digital-image-processing, image-mosaic

Is it possible to download 1:2000 scale of a town using google earth image? If divide the whole area into grid and mosaic them is an option, how it is done using google earth? I tried using grid. But there is no option to change the grid size.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a guide to divide maps and download them from google earth at :
[Downloading mosaic Google Earth maps and rectify them automatically in their correct coordinates](https://www.facebook.com/notes/gis-elshayal-smart-gis/downloading-mosaic-google-earth-maps-and-rectify-them-automatically-in-their-cor/10150153255668323).

However after looking into it further it looks like there are simpler ways to do this using the [Google Map Ripper from Blue Black Works](http://www.blueblackworks.com/googlemapsripper/overview). This should provide you with the ability to set the scale that you desire as well.